# What is the point of sorting by PID and username in top?

Tags: linux, top

I've been using the `top` program to find the most CPU and memory hungry programs on linux systems. Only recently did I discover the multi-window mode. The default windows number 2 (teal) and 4 (yellow) show processes in descending PID and username order, respectively.

Is there any point in sorting the columns this way, considering that you cannot scroll the windows? The PID numbers will saturate close to 32k, and only Zach and Zoe's processes are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any point in sorting the columns this way, considering that
>   you cannot scroll the windows?

Why aren't you able to scroll the windows?

With `a` you cycle the current active window
with UP DOWN PGUP PGDOWN (but even LEFT - RIGHT) you scroll the active one.
See the man page `5c. SCROLLING a Window`

Comment: I knew that you can cycle windows with `a`. However, arrow and page keys just print "Unknown command" and in the man pages there's no section with the name you mentioned. For the record, my top version is `top: procps version 3.2.8`

Comment: ok my version is  `procps-ng version 3.3.3` see here what's new [here](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps/source/2f96eef7f86a12b81badef1c91ec2d503ae4029d:NEWS#L8) line 204. I suppose you need a new version.